# why to call doGet() function

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript. My question is if i want to call doGet() in script than how can i Call it? What should be the Parameters of function? and why to call doGet() function in script? I tried some Examples. I tried this too. Is this right way to call this function?

```
function doGet(e)
{
   var payload = {
      "StartDateTime" : Utilities.formatDate(newDate(),"GMT", "yyyy-mm-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'"),
      "EndDateTime" : Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-mm-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'")
         };
    var JSONString = JSON.stringify(payload);
    var JSONOutput = ContentService.createTextOutput(JSONString);
    JSONOutput.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    return JSONOutput;
}
```

Comment: You just need to call it, for example in a button: `<button onclick="doGet()">Click me</button>`

Comment: I have written script . when i m calling doGet(e) it shows error "The script completed but did not return anything."

Answer (score -1):

doGet recieves one parameter `e` but it is not used anywhere.
So you can call doGet without any arguments like

```
<body onload="doGet();">
```